# Telerik Chart in IE8 error telerik.chart.min.js, line 1 character 74000

Tags: internet-explorer-8, telerik-mvc

We are working with Telerik MVC Extension version 2011.3.1115, and JQuery 1.6.3.

OK, this works in all the browsers we have checked but IE8.  That includes IE7, works fine in IE7, and it work on IE8 in IE7 Compatibility mode.  IE8, Chrome, and Firefox are all fine.

But, in IE8 (in IE8 standards mode) rendering a pie chart with Telerik Chart, I get errors on telerik.chart.min.js, line 1 character 74000.

Just seeing if someone else has run into this already

```
        var graph = helper.Telerik().Chart(data)
            .Name(Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
            .ChartArea(area => area
                                   .Background("#fff")
                                   .Margin(0)
            )
            .PlotArea(area => area
                                  .Background("#fff")
                                  .Margin(0)
            )
            .Series(series => series
                                  .Pie("Value", "Designation")
                                  .Name(title)
                                  .Padding(0)
                                  .Overlay(ChartPieSeriesOverlay.None)
                                  .StartAngle(90)
                                  )
            .SeriesColors(seriesColors)
            .Transitions(false)
            .Legend(false)
            .Tooltip(tooltip => tooltip.Visible(true).Template("<#= value #>").Padding(0).Border(0, "transparent")).ToHtmlString();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Over time, we removed all of the Telerik chart and replaced them with Flot.